# Os crawlers/bots/web-spiders dos motores de busca copiam e acessam o href de um link, ou "clicam" no <a></a> para ser redirecionados?

Tags: web-crawler

Eu tenho essa dúvida, porque eu quero desenvolver um portal em Ajax, mas que as páginas possam ser acessadas também via url.

**Minha dúvida é:**  Se o `<a> </a>` tiver com `return false` ao clicar, o web-spider não vai conseguir seguir o `href` dele? Ou ele copia o `href` e acessa, sem seguir as instruções javascript no documento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o mais importante aqui é lembrar que, a maior parte dos serviços de busca, tentam prezar pela usabilidade/navegabilidade/experiência do usuário - não como o site foi feito em si.

Falado isso, tudo varia de crawler/spider de cada provedor. Enquanto o spider do Google executa o Javascript/CSS (https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.htm), crawlers de provedores menores podem não utilizar. Logo, seu site em AJAX seguiria as instruções do Javascript sem problemas :)